# Not able to inject HashMap Object using util namespace setter dependency injection in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject HashMap Object using util namespace but not able to get HashMap class for that Object (LinkedHashMap class name is getting printed.) 
Not able to figure out why this is happening.

I am using below Spring jars in this test:

```
1. spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
2. spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
3. spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
4. spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar 
5. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

1. Bean Class :

   ```
           package com.vitp.pkg1;

           import java.util.HashMap;

           public class ActualCollections {

               private HashMap<String,Integer> student;

               public void setStudent(HashMap<String, Integer> student) {
                   this.student = student;
               }

               public void displayData()
               {
                    System.out.println("Map data(Student<name,rollnumber>) : ---default is LinkedHashMap And actual is :: "+student.getClass().getName());
                    for(String key : student.keySet())
                    {
                        System.out.println(key+"::"+student.get(key));
                    }
               }
           }
   ```
2. Driver class to test the output :

   ```
           package com.vitp.start;

           import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
           import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

           import com.vitp.pkg1.ActualCollections;
           import com.vitp.pkg1.DefaultCollections;

           public class ActualCollectionObjectInjectionTest {

               public static void main(String... s)
               {
                   ApplicationContext beans = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/vitp/resources/particular_collection.xml");
                   ActualCollections pc = (ActualCollections) beans.getBean("pc");
                   pc.displayData();
               }
           }
   ```
3. xml configuration file :

   ```
           <!--In this case we need to make use of util namespace so will use xsd instate of dtd.-->

           <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

               <bean id="pc" class="com.vitp.pkg1.ActualCollections">
                   <!--Set Map attribute with setter injection-->
                   <property name="student">
                       <util:map map-class="java.util.HashMap">
                           <!-- demonstrating various ways on values for entry-->
                           <entry key="Sachin" value="1"/>
                           <!--way2-->               
                           <entry key="Rahul">
                               <value>2</value>
                           </entry>
                           <!--way3-->
                           <entry key="Vinayak" value-ref="three"/>
                           <!--way4-->
                           <entry key="Salman">
                               <ref bean="four"/>
                           </entry>
                       </util:map>
                   </property>
               </bean>

               <bean id="three" class="java.lang.Integer">
                   <constructor-arg index="0">
                       <value>3</value>
                   </constructor-arg>
               </bean>

               <bean id="four" class="java.lang.Integer">
                   <constructor-arg index="0">
                       <value>4</value>
                   </constructor-arg>
               </bean>

           </beans>
   ```

And the result is :

```
            Sep 09, 2018 7:17:03 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
            INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@27f8302d: startup date [Sun Sep 09 19:17:03 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
            Sep 09, 2018 7:17:03 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
            INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/vitp/resources/particular_collection.xml]
            Map data(Student<name,rollnumber>) : ---default is LinkedHashMap And actual is :: java.util.LinkedHashMap
            Rahul::2
            Vinayak::3
            Sachin::1
            Salman::4
```

I am expectting It should be HashMap class.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap extends HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing id property for Map. If you put id for map, it work.
Working code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="pc" class="com.vitp.pkg1.ActualCollections">
        <property name="student" ref="someId"/>
    </bean>

    <util:map id="someId" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <!-- demonstrating various ways on values for entry-->
        <entry key="Sachin" value="1"/>
        <!--way2-->               
        <entry key="Rahul">
            <value>2</value>
        </entry>
        <!--way3-->
        <entry key="Vinayak" value-ref="three"/>
        <!--way4-->
        <entry key="Salman">
            <ref bean="four"/>
        </entry>
    </util:map>

    <bean id="three" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <value>3</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="four" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <value>4</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Tested but not getting expected result.(getting same result- LinkedHashMap)

If I make it to 'java.util.TreeMap' (did changes in 1. Bean Class : HashMap to Map)
Getting expected output as below:

`Map data(Student<name,rollnumber>) : ---default is LinkedHashMap And actual is :: java.util.TreeMap
Rahul::2
Sachin::1
Salman::4
Vinayak::3
`